# VWO script with onClick already present

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'am sort of responsible or A/B testing at my company. We use Visual Website Optimizer. It's smooth sailing up until now. Mainly html/css coding/editing. Now I have to use what is called a "Customized Conversion Goal". Basically it means that the system triggers whenever a custom JavaScript function is called on the URL/page.

The proper way of triggering according to VWO is using the "onClick":

```
<a onclick="if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) =='function'){  
_vis_opt_goal_conversion(200); _vis_opt_pause(500);}" href="#"><span>Sign Up</span></a>
```

Although, if you edit the code directly you mess upp the dynamic content on the page so you have to (?) use jquery, apparently. So then you have a little console in the VWO system where you can put your javascript/jquery (and css) into. This would be the way to use the above mentioned code then:

```
vwo_$('.rLink a').attr('onClick', 'if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == "function") {     
_vis_opt_goal_conversion(208); _vis_opt_pause(500); }');
```

This then assumes you want to add the onClick to the anchor inside the .rLink class. Now, this works. I've tried it. But of course, life isn't that simple. Now I have to add this onClick function to an element that already has an onClick. I understand that you can't have  two onClicks in the same element(?). Right? I tried to "inject it to the div containing the anchor but that didn't work either. So, how do I solve this little mystery? Remember I can't edit the page "hands on" in anyway, just inject new code using the little built in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, changing the `onClick` attribute is not a good way to trigger click events. Instead, you should attach a click event. In jQuery this is done with [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Try adding a [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler:

```
vwo_$('.rLink a').click(function(){
    if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == "function") {     
        _vis_opt_goal_conversion(208);
    }
});
```

Also worth mentioning, `typeof` is an *operator* and not a function. There is no point in doing `typeof(x)` . You can instead do `typeof _vis_opt_top_initialize  === "function"`

Comment: Thank you! Love the .click :) I've done some initial testing and it seems to work on my testpage. Going to test it live tomorrow. I noticed you skipped the "_vis_opt_pause(500);" part - is it unnecessary?

Comment: No, I did not notice it :) Note that instead of passing your script as string you're writing actual code which should make debugging easier. If this solved your problem please consider accepting this answer.